# Java - JDBC - DB2 - "CLI0129E No more handles"

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

Cracked my head on this for few days and now have come here for some help/ideas

Server: Solaris
JDK : 1.6
DB: Db2

### Scenario:

Running a batch job, which has about 6000+ records, but when around 2740 records are reached, get below error
COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0129E  No more handles. SQLSTATE=HY014

This is batch job, no connection pool but have seen code use "COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2DataSource"

I have gone through every bit of code that goes through the flow & every single method has finally where all DB resources are closed using .close().

Looking for "no more handles" online suggests calling from freeing methods or increasing CLIPKG (which means overhead for performance)

Dont have any tools on Solaris to monitor the connections open etc on the server. All the more difficult since its not a pool.

Has anyone faced any such issue or can help me with what next.

### Sample Code called everytime a row is processed(about 3000 rows for now):

```
Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement prepStmtSeq = null;
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;

        try 
        {
            LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 37");
            conn = getConnection();

            prepStmtSeq = conn.prepareStatement(getSqlStmt("getNextDocumentId"));
            prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(getSqlStmt("createDocument"));

            LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 43");

            for (Document document: documents) {
                ResultSet resultsSeq = null;
                PreparedStatement prepStmtType = null;
                try {
                    resultsSeq = prepStmtSeq.executeQuery();
                    LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 50");
                    resultsSeq.next();
                    LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 52");
                    document.setDocumentId(resultsSeq.getLong(1));
                    prepStmt.setLong(1, document.getDocumentId());
                    prepStmt.setString(2, document.getCorrelationId());
                    prepStmt.setShort(3, document.getDocumentTypeCd());
                    prepStmt.setShort(4, document.getDocumentStatusCd());
                    prepStmt.setTimestamp(5, document.getCreatedDate());
                    prepStmt.setString(6, document.getCreatedBy());
                    LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 60");
                    prepStmt.executeUpdate();
                    LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 62");
                    if (document instanceof ScannedDocument) {
                        ScannedDocument scannedDocument = (ScannedDocument)document;
                        LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 65");
                        prepStmtType = conn.prepareStatement(getSqlStmt("createScannedDocument"));
                        prepStmtType.setLong(1, scannedDocument.getDocumentId());
                        prepStmtType.setDate(2, scannedDocument.getScannedDate());
                        prepStmtType.setString(3, scannedDocument.getDrn());
                        prepStmtType.executeUpdate();
                        LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 71");
                    }
                }
                finally 
                {
                    LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 76");
                    if (prepStmtType != null) 
                    {
                        prepStmtType.close();

                    }
                    if (resultsSeq != null) 
                    {
                        resultsSeq.close();

                    }
                    LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 87");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            String[] message = {ex.getMessage(), getClass().getName()};
            throw new DataAccessException("SQLCode." + ex.getErrorCode(), message, ex);
        }
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 100");
                if (prepStmtSeq != null) 
                {
                    prepStmtSeq.close();
                }
                if (prepStmt != null) 
                {
                    prepStmt.close();
                }
                if (conn != null) 
                {
                    conn.close();
                }
                LOG.info("DocumentDAO::createDocuments 113");
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                String[] message = {ex.getMessage(), getClass().getName()};
                throw new DataAccessException("SQLCode." + ex.getErrorCode(), message, ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Posting the source code or atleast a fragment of it which depicts your problem will help others to help you out..

Comment: Apologies. Added code above in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply my friend...

You are using two PreparedStatements

- prepStmtSeq
- prepStmt

When you execute the first PreparedStatement(prepStmtSeq) you get a resultSet and connection to database is closed..
So when the next PreparedStatement(prepStmt) is executed connection is closed..

So try this solution and get back to me....

```
class Database 
{
public  Connection conn;
private  Statement stat;
//Creating and establishing connection with database...
//Called at first in each method because connection is opened only when required...
public Database() 
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:South2Books.db"); 
        stat = conn.createStatement(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
}

public synchronized PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String s)
{
    try 
    {
        PreparedStatement prep= conn.prepareStatement(s);
        System.out.println("CONN "+conn.isClosed());
        if(conn.isClosed())
        {
            System.out.println("CONNECTION RECREATED");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:South2Books.db"); 
        }
        return prep;

    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    return null;
}
// If you want to do other transactions
public synchronized void execute(String s)
{
    try {
        stat.execute(s);
    } catch (SQLException e) 
    {e.printStackTrace();}
}
public synchronized void executeUpdate(String s)
{
    try {
        stat.execute(s);
    } catch (SQLException e) 
    {e.printStackTrace();}
}
public synchronized ResultSet executeQuery(String s)
{
    try 
    {
        return stat.executeQuery(s);
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    return null;
}
public void close()
{
    try
    {
        if(conn.isClosed()==false)
        {
            stat.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
}
}
```

This method is far better than the previous one because you create one object of class database to do all your transactions..(Object oriented programming)..
Even if you multi-thread this there wont be a problem..

So now the three statements you need to change are :

```
prepStmtSeq = db.prepareStatement(getSqlStmt("getNextDocumentId"));
prepStmt = db.prepareStatement(getSqlStmt("createDocument"));
prepStmtType = db.prepareStatement(getSqlStmt("createScannedDocument"));
```

Comment: thanks Vaibhav. there is a custom framework static method, that I'm using. However, still looking  into the code. Is there any specific reason why you call close() after prepStmtType.executeUpdate(); ??

Comment: there is no connection pool implementation, but rather plain old JDBC and trying to process 2700 plus rows.